# RichTextBox removing unknown tags

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, richtextbox, rtf

I'm using richtextbox to show rtf documents created with MS Word
I need to show contents of a document, like the "document schema" in MS Word, which creates schema by
using style tags "\s[number of style]"
I have a problem, which occurs when I load my file in richtextbox. Attempting to get the RTF text only
returns known tags, omitting all the unknown ones.
I use the following code for loading the file

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(file));
rtbViewer.Selection.Load(stream,DataFormats.Rtf);
stream.Close();
```

I've managed to make a contents by regex-searching through the input string file. I get the source file and
get its text in a string (it would be with all its rtf-tags), then I search for style tags and get information about
level and text. Everything is  ok as long as the user doesn't change text and then try to save it.
The problem is that when I load file in richtextbox I miss all information about content. When I try to save the
changed document I get Rtf text from richtextbox but it doesn't contain style tags.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
rtbViewer.Selection.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

How can I get all tags from my source file?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
<RichTextBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,30,0,0" Name="rtfMain"        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />

rtfMain.Selection.Load(new FileStream(@"C:\temp\document.rtf", FileMode.Open), DataFormats.Rtf);
```